# why this showing module not found error ,either i installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module

i am not able install 'copyleakscloud' library. I already installed 'copyleaks' library, but i need 'copyleakscloud' and i'm not getting any version of this library. please help!

Comment: Do you have multiple python environments installed?

Comment: how can i install this, actually i'm a beginner, so please help

Comment: How did you run the Python program? Through command line or Python IDLE or any other tool?

Comment: vs code editor , but installed python 3.8

Comment: actually i installed 'copyleaks' module and it was successfully installed but i need 'copyleakscloud' and there is no any module.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about [this library](https://github.com/Copyleaks/Python-Plagiarism-Checker)?
You need to open a prompt (cmd on Windows or Terminal on macOS) and run
`pip install copyleaks`

Comment: yaa , i already installed it but i need 'copyleakscloud' module because this source code i get from github reposittory of copyleak.

Comment: but there is not any version of 'copyleakscloud'. why?

Comment: Check what they say here on [their repository](https://github.com/Copyleaks/Python-Plagiarism-Checker#usage)

Answer (score 0):

The `CopyleaksCloud` is bundled with the `copyleaks` library. You can use it with the following code lines:

```py
from copyleaks.copyleakscloud import CopyleaksCloud
cloud = CopyleaksCloud('ProductName', 'YOUR_EMAIL_HERE', 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE')# You can change the product.
```